# How to add new row to dataframe when I only want to add two values and set the rest blanc?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

a new week starts with a new problem :-). I have a dataframe and want to add some new rows efficiently. In general I have a dataframe with multiple columns but when I add a row I only need to fill two columns. Here is a minimal example of my problem:

```
data1 = {"t1": ["a1", ""]
       , "t2": ["", "d1"]
       , "t3": ["e1", ""]
       , "t4": ["", "h1"]}
df_big = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df_big

>    t1  t2  t3  t4
> 0  a1      e1     
> 1      d1      h1
```

From some analysis I get some data that is basically a row of an other dataframe:

```
data
> t1  t4
> b1  c1
```

and want to add it to the table. The result looks like this:

```
>    t1  t2  t3  t4
> 0  a1      e1     
> 1      d1      h1
> 2  b1          c1
```

the cols in the new row that I do not specify should be empty or np.nan

DO you have an idea how to do this (efficiently)?

Best

P :-)

Comment: `df_big.append(data)`.

Comment: `df = df_big.append(data)` make sure assign it back

Comment: okay... that makes me feel bad ;-), thanks for your answer :-)